# xterm overflowing from the sides

Tags: debian, virtualbox, xterm

I have performed a minimal Debian install in a VirtualBox. I have also setup `lightdm`. Install VirtualBox Guest Additions as well. Everything is working except that the `xterm` is overflowing from the right edge of screen and bottom edge of the screen. I cannot check for what is happening below that. I have created the configuration file .Xresources and set a very less xterm geometry 100x80. When I set the lower geometry I can contain the edges of the right side but from the bottom edge it still overflows from the screen resolution. What is the basic process of setting the xterm to be contained inside the xrandr resolution?

[image]

I have written clear in the screen but it is not inside my view.

I have used a resolution of `1920x1080` and set the xterm geometry to be `1600x900+0+0` for this image.

Comment: xterm only works with window sizes that are a multiple of the font height/width.  Depending on the window manager, that can make xterm extend off-screen.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I am using X Windows Manager. What do you really mean by multiple of font height/width? Can u show some examples?

Comment: @ThomasDickey I got it working...

Comment: I was under the impression that installing xorg packages install x window manager as well.

Comment: Usually, but you can install clients easily without the server or window managers.  It depends on what you ask for.